# Style SelectedItem in ListBox upon Load WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I have a `ListBox`, as such:

```
<ListBox
    //other stuff
    ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
          <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"> 
                <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                             <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
                       </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

`ViewModel.cs:`

```
public SomeType SelectedThing
{
     get => selectedThing;
     set => //set with INotifyPropertyChanged
}

public ObservableCollection<SomeType> ViewModels
{
     get => viewModels;
     set => //set with INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

It's possible that `SelectedThing` is defined in the `ViewModel` when loading the app, so I want it to be styled accordingly.

It works great when I open the app and then click on an item, but how can the style be applied on load?

I tried with:

```
<Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple" />
      </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

But every item of the `ListBox` is enabled, so it applies it to every item upon load.

**EDIT:**

After debugging a bit, I found out that when setting `SelectedThing` on load, `SelectedItem` remains `null`.

**EDIT:**

Here is the `OnLoaded` method in the `ViewModel`, where I am setting `SelectedThing` if the user has selected it while previously using the app. The purpose is to keep the selection after closing and reopening the app.

```
public IAsyncRelayCommand OnLoadedCommand { get; set; }
```

In the constructor:

```
OnLoadedCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(OnLoaded);
```

In the View:

```
<b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <b:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
    </b:EventTrigger>
</b:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The actual method:

```
public async Task OnLoaded()
{
    //other stuff
    if (App.Current.Properties.Contains(nameof(SelectedThing)))
    {
          var selected = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeType>(App.Current.Properties[nameof(SelectedThing)].ToString());
          SelectedThing = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set `SelectedThing` and `SelectedItem` isn't set, your binding is not working or you are not implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly. Impossible to say based on the code you have posted. It's not a reproducible example.

Comment: `SelectedItem` is set after clicking on an item in the ListBox and behaves correctly -> the binding does work. I am also implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` as I have shown in my code. The problem is that `SelectedThing` could be set in an `OnLoaded` method in the ViewModel and this way, `SelectedItem` is not set.

Comment: Yes, it should be if you raise change notifications. Again, you're not showing all relevant parts of your code. And why and how are you setting a view model property in `OnLoaded`?

Comment: I have updated the code with more relevant things, thanks.

Comment: Is `selected` really present in the source collection?

Comment: Yes, always. The user selects an item from the ListBox, closes the app and when he reopens it, I want the same thing to be selected and its style to be applied (background colour is purple). That's all.

Comment: That's not what is asked...What do you set `SelectedThing` in your OnLoaded() method? Is this value present in the `ViewModels` collection?

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the setter of `SelectedThing` the `App.Current.Properties[nameof(SelectedThing)]` is updated with the new value. If it doesn't exist yet, it's created.

Comment: You were right! It's not in the collection and I had to do a `var selectedViewModel = ViewModels.Where(x => x.SelectedThing == selected.SelectedThing).FirstOrDefault();
SelectedThing = selectedViewModel;` Million thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why there is no item selected is because you are setting the `SelectedThing` source property to a value that's not in the `ViewModels` source collection.

As you have already discovered, this works better:

```
var selectedViewModel = ViewModels.Where(x => x.SelectedThing == selected.SelectedThing).FirstOrDefault();
SelectedThing = selectedViewModel;
```

The item to be selected must be present in the source collection.